# How to display an array of object in a ng-repeat with angular js

Tags: html, api, trello

Why can't `tab_cards` (array of objects) be assigned to `$scope.cards`?

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="trelloApp" id="cardContainer">
    <div ng-controller="displayCardsCtrl">
        <article ng-show="cards.length">
            <ul id="card-list">
                {{cards}}
                <li ng-repeat="card in cards" >
                    <div class="view">
                        <center><h1>Titre:</h1></center>
                        <span>{{card.name}}</span>
                        <span class="close" ng-click="removeCard(card)">x</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

Before this Javascript I have the code to connect to Trello's API.

Javascript:

```
var tab_cards = [];
var trelloApp = angular.module('trelloApp',[]);

Trello.get("/boards/M1msSdbt/cards", getCardsSuccess);

function getCardsSuccess(data){    
    for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++){
           tab_cards.push(data[i]);
    }
}

trelloApp.controller('displayCardsCtrl',
function ($scope,tab_cards) {
     $scope.cards = tab_cards;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put Trello.get function and the success handler inside controller and replace `$scope.cards = tab_cards;` with

```
$scope.apply(function(){
  $scope.cards = tab_cards;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your 'trello' function is assyncronous, maybe your request is not getting a response until the lifecycle of the angular creates the view. In my case when i needed to load assyncronous data and update a view i use an angular service and work with angular 'promises'. I recommend you to do the same thing instead to use callback in your function because with the promises the lifecycle forces an update of the bindings and with callbacks its not happens.

Thats a better way, but if you don't have time to refactor your code use just a $scope.$apply() in your $scope.cards = tab_cards;